# batch to repair local area connection Windows XP

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, windows-xp

I have a sporadic internet connection that shows high ping and low bandwidth. I can manually fix it with LAN repair but it happens again in a short while. I'm looking for a batch that can repair it automatically on timed intervals. On Windows XP. I don't know what it is that the LAN repair is doing so i can't even start the batch. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, try this batch

```
@echo off
:begin
ipconfig /renew
arp -d
nbtstat -R
nbtstat -RR
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
ping -n 60 127.0.0.1 >nul
goto begin
```

hope this helps